# Php proper time conversion for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, converters

Getting time as following in json result from Google API:

```
2014-08-25T20:02:24.000Z
```

how to convert and prepare it for MySQL `datetime` field?

Comment: Set the columns data type to `datetime`

Comment: @LozCheroneツ and to insert as it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$dateTime=new DateTime('2014-08-25T20:02:24.000Z');
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
```

outputs as

**2014-08-25 20:02:24** [mysql DATETIME format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

As a simple [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) representation it is [*almost* what MySQL understands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html). The only thing that is problematic issue is the "Z" as MySQL does not support time-zones nor does it ignore "Z".

Thus simply touch up the format a bit (such is not a general solution for all dates but it *does* present a valid solution for this problem, when the date is not used or checked pre-SQL);

```
$iso = "2014-08-25T20:02:24.000Z";      // literal JSON text
$iso = preg_replace("/Z$/", "", $iso);  // -> "2014-08-25T20:02:24.000"
```

And insert it into MySQL as normal ([*with placeholders*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)) like a string;

```
$msqli_stmt->bind_param("s", $iso);
$pdo_stmt->bindValue(":dt", $iso);
```

Consider this SQL example;

```sql
create table x (y datetime)
insert into x (y) values ('2014-08-25T20:02:24.000')
select * from x
--> August, 25 2014 20:02:24+0000
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [ISO 8601 date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). You can convert it directly to a `DateTime` object with:

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-08-25T20:02:24.000Z');
```

Or to a timestamp to be used with the classic PHP time functions with `strtotime()`:

```
$time = strtotime('2014-08-25T20:02:24.000Z');
```

Once you have that simply convert it to the format MySQL uses,  `Y-m-d H:i:s`, by using one of those:

```
$to_mysql = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$to_mysql = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
```